# Помогите с задачей! Точнее подскажите с чего начать!

Tags: java, алгоритм, шифрование

Есть задача, в которой сказано, что нужно написать программу, которая находит в заданном телефонном номере подстроку максимальной длины, соответствующую слову из словаря.
2 — ABC, 3 — DEF, 4 — GHI,
5 — JKL, 6 — MNO, 7 — PQRS, 8 — TUV, 9 — WXYZ .
Все сделать на Java.

Comment: Покамест в вашем вопросе не видно вопроса.

Comment: А начать стоит с пустого проекта, или с инсталляции IDE, если ещё не установлено.

Comment: Все установлено. Занимаюсь строками,  но не могу придумать алгоритм решения этой задачи! Я понимаю, что надо ввести номер, далее каждой цифре присвоить значение буквы согласно условию. НО как сделать так, чтобы на выходе получалось слово?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слишком длинно для комментария...

Для начала - определиться с длиной телефонного номера.

Затем, раздельно для каждой группы букв:

1. Выбрать из словаря слова соответствующей длины, которые начинаются с букв данной группы
2. Оцифровать их.
3. Для чисел одинаковой длины отбросить первую цифру, после чего отсортировать по возрастанию.
4. Устранить повторы чисел
5. Дать каждому массиву уникальное имя.

Расшифровку номеров вести бинарным поиском по соответствующим массивам, начиная с массива наибольшей длины.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю пойти от обратного:

- Словарь отсортирован по убыванию длины
- Перебираете все слова из словаря
- Переводите каждое слово в число
- Ищем вхождение числа в исходном номере